# Is there a need to install print server services on Windows 2012 if the printer will be shared?

Tags: network-printer, print-server, windows-server-2012

We currently have a Windows 2012 server connected to a network printer and we would like to have centralized management of the printer rather than installing it on each workstation.

As this is a small outfit, there isn't a need for Activie Directory and all computers belong to the same workgroup.

If we want all workstations to have access to the network printer, is it better to share the printer installed on the Windows 2012 server or install the print server services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On server 2012, you will need to install printer services to be able to manage the printer centrally.

[This](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831468.aspx) is an overview of Print and Document Services, including Print Server, Distributed Scan Server and Fax Server in Windows Server 2012.

Before installing Print and Document Services in Windows Server 2012, consider the Printing and Scanning scenarios that your organization will benefit from and what kind of advanced features are required.

There is a great [Technet FAQ](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134159.aspx) about the services in windows server, and how you choose to implement it depends on your environment and goals.

Comment: @G Koe - Is file sharing enabled by default in Windows 2012 and if it isn't and should i install printer services, will it enable file sharing?

Comment: Print and Document Services are separate from file and storage services in Serer 2012.